# @Before advise with matching parameters type

Tags: spring, spring-aop

I am trying to add @Before advise for a method having four parameters

```
 public void genericExploits(String game, RequestType requestType, String fileName, ExploitGameDetails expGameDetails)
```

I know that for custom parameters i have to use fully qualified name.What is used for Generic one like String ,Boolean.

I want to exactly create **@Before** annotation with all parameters same for calling method.

```
@Before("execution(public void Exploits(com.openbet.fog.it.torch.exploit.ExploitGameDetails,..))")
public void exploitSetup() throws Exception {
        createFogUser(GenericExploitsITData.BALANCE, GenericExploitsITData.CURRENCY_CODE);
        torch.setTestRecovery(false);
    }
```

I tried this for my this method:

```
public void genericExploits(String game, RequestType requestType, String fileName, ExploitGameDetails expGameDetails) throws Exception
    {

        //some code
}
```

I dont want to use wild card like (..) and wants exactly to place ,y parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The general scheme for method pointcuts is:

```java
public void my.package.ClassName.methodName(fully.qualified.Parameter, another.Parameter, ...)
```

So in your case the solution would be something like:

```java
@Before("execution(public void package.Exploits.genericExploits(java.lang.String, package.RequestType, java.lang.String, package.ExploitGameDetails))")
```

**Please note:** You need to replace `package` by the actual package names.

Comment: I revised your text because even though your suggestion is correct the answer was hard to understand. I also added code formatting and syntax highlighting. I advise you to give your answer some more love next time. Brief answers are okay, but a minimum of comprehensive explanation would be good. Thank you.